# Can I cast generic type to Dictionary<,> in C#?

Tags: c#

I have programm settings in some dictionary collections.
And I need to update default settings (**src** dictionary) by settings from config file (**dst** dictionary).
So, I write a generic extension method which doesn't work for dictionary inside dictionary:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Update<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U> src, Dictionary<T, U> dst)
    {
        // Update values by keys
        var keys = src.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
        foreach (var key in keys)
            if (dst.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                if (typeof(U).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                {                                                    // Error in recursively calling:
                    var d1 = src[key] as Dictionary<object, object>; // d1 is null, but it is Dictionary<,>
                    var d2 = dst[key] as Dictionary<object, object>; // d2 is null, but it is Dictionary<,>
                    d1.Update(d2);                                   // How can I call it?
                }
                else
                    src[key] = dst[key];
            }

        // Append not exist values
        keys = dst.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
        foreach (var key in keys)
            if (!src.ContainsKey(key))
                src.Add(key, dst[key]);
    }
}
```

Can I cast class **U** to unknown type of **Dictionary<,>** and then call **Update()** method recursively?

Comment: Normally, assignments go from `dst` to `src`, and not the other way around.

Comment: Can you explain your objective here? Why do you need unknown type dictionary here?

Comment: Because, there are four dictionaries with different enum keys and values.
And settings may become more.
Now there are four realizations for each dictionary, but I try to improve my code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn *From* destination *to* source? That doesn't make any sense to me. Source is where you start, destination is where you end up.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn, your remark is not resolve a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IDictionay , Not use generic Type , Possible can do that , 
I have not tried

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Update(this IDictionary src, IDictionary dst)
    {
        foreach (object srcKey in src.Keys)
        {
            foreach (object dstKey in dst.Keys)
            {
                if (dst.Contains(srcKey))
                {
                    IDictionary d1 = src[srcKey] as IDictionary;
                    IDictionary d2 = dst[srcKey] as IDictionary;
                    if (d1 != null && d2 != null)
                    {
                        d1.Update(d2);
                    }
                    else
                        src[srcKey] = dst[srcKey];
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (object dstKey in dst.Keys)
            if (!src.Contains(dstKey))
                src.Add(dstKey, dst[dstKey]);
    }
}
```

And Use like this.

```
Dictionary<object, object> a = new Dictionary<object, object>();
Dictionary<object, object> b = new Dictionary<object, object>();
a.Update(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TimChang, now my code is:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Update(this IDictionary src, IDictionary dst)
    {
        foreach (var key in dst.Keys)
            if (src.Contains(key))
            {
                if (src[key] is IDictionary a &&
                    dst[key] is IDictionary b)
                    a.Update(b);
                else
                    src[key] = dst[key];
            }
            else
            {
                src.Add(key, dst[key]);
            }
    }
}
```